# Subscribe to behaviourSubject after last update

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have component 1 which sends data to the shared service:

```
//Component 1
  printPage() {
    let pages: Page[] = [];
    pages.push(this.selectedPage);
    this.printService.print(pages);
  }
```

on the shared service I have a behavior subject holding the array of pages I want to print and I make next. then I will create an Iframe on the document which is routed to "/pages/print/".

```
export class PrintService {
  private pagesSource = new BehaviorSubject<Page[]>([]);
  currentPages = this.pagesSource.asObservable();
  constructor(

  ) { }
  print (pages: Page[]) {
    this.pagesSource.next(pages);
    let oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
    oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
    oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
    oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
    oHiddFrame.src = "/pages/print/"; //-> Print Component
    document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
  }
}
```

On the component routed to /pages/print I'm subscribing to the subject on the printService.

```
//Print Component
  constructor(
    private printService: PrintService,
  ) {
    this.printService.currentPages.subscribe(pages => {
      this.pages = pages; // always gives me undefined
    });
  }
```

Reproduction demo:
https://github.com/dazzzed/iframe-com-service

Couldn't make a plnkr since I wasn't able to append the Iframe of the component.

So, this should make the array of pages available when I subscribe to the currentPages on the print Service right? Instead I'm always getting undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to subscribe to observable inside ngOnInit instead of constructor?

Comment: I did, still get undefined...

Comment: where have you provided this service? `[providers]` array?

Comment: Yes, in the app module file

Comment: The code we are seeing is correct, please create a demo that showcases your issue.

Comment: https://github.com/dazzzed/iframe-com-service

Couldn't make a plnkr since I wasn't able to append the Iframe of the component.

Comment: your project does not work, it throws error when trying to run it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I added the missing files, it should work now :)